# Regionalise the angular app at run time for different countries

Tags: javascript, angular, internationalization, requirejs

We have made a global app where we want to regionalise it to separate countries. Some countries has similar functionality defined as in global components in angular. But some countries require whole new functional changes in particular components and we have to use the same code base.

How can we load these components based on country after login into app by maintaining that component in two separate folders named with country codes? Do we have to use requireJS for this?

Comment: Welcome to SO! This question has a very low quality. Please make the effort to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: RequireJS is quite old, I would not recommend it. You can achieve same functionality by using Factories and / or Strategies

Comment: @jasie i dont really belong to english speaking country im sorry ...i guess i have explained my problem well though

Comment: @DamianDziaduch can u post any example code pls??? Can we do that using webpack????

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using the concept of `Dynamic component loader`. [Reference](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader)

An example implementatino for this can be as follows:

```
import { Injectable,ComponentFactoryResolver, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class DynamicComponentLoadingService{


  constructor(private cfr: ComponentFactoryResolver) {}

  async loadComponent(vcr: ViewContainerRef, country: string) {
    // component-1
    const { Component1 } = await import('./compoennt1/component1.component');

    const { Component2 } = await import('./component2/component2.component');

    vcr.clear();
    // for instance we want to load component-1 for US
    let component : any = country === 'US' ? Component1: Component2;
   
    return vcr.createComponent(
      this.cfr.resolveComponentFactory(component))    
  }
}
```

Here is a [detailed post](https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/loading-components-dynamically-in-angular-cd13b9fdb715) explaining the same.

Comment: but if we had to add many countries then we have to edit this service file using if loop for many countries right??? We need something like based on country it has to load that particular country component by itself ...do we have to configure that inside webpack???